# Jenkins does not checkout correct version when repository is the same as the shared library

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a git repository that contains:

- a jenkins shared library
- documentation for the shared library
- a Jenkinsfile used to build and deploy the documentation

My Jenkinsfile is using that same shared library, but on a fixed version.

I am expecting Jenkins to:

- checkout the shared library `v0.1.0` (for example) in `$WORKSPACE@libs`
- checkout the `feat/new-stuff` branch in `$WORKSPACE`

Where `$WORKSPACE` is the path to the workspace set up by Jenkins

But, from what I experience, the checked out branch is not `feat/new-stuff` but the tag `v0.1.0`.

I would like to avoid having my documentation and source code in different repositories.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: What's your Jenkins and plugin versions?

Comment: this is Jenkins 2.150.1 unfortunately I don't have access to the plugin list (corportate jenkins + not admin)